# Windows 7 mapped network drives disconnected for new users

Tags: windows-7, networking

The issue is that on all Windows computers on our Windows domain, when a new user logs in to a computer for the first time all drives are mapped (via user logon script) but all appear in a disconnected state with the red cross icon.

Even though they are disconnected I can double click on any drive to connect it instantly or I can just have the user reboot the computer at which point the same script runs again and all drives appear normally. The disconnection issue never occurs again for that user unless they experience an actual connection issue.

All the logon script actually does is remove drives that exist and map fresh ones.

e.g. :

> net use /delete F: \\server\shareF
>    net use /delete G: \\server\shareG
>    net use F: \\server\shareF /yes
>    net use G: \\server\shareG /yes

Comment: If you can click on one and it reconnects immediately, what is it that you are after? Do you just receive too many questions from users regarding the supposed disconnected state?

Comment: It just inconveniences the end user and myself. When they log in for the first time any application that uses the mapped network drive as a source for it's data can't connect, the drive needs to be connected and then data can be accessed. It means that I have to hold their hand through every first time login when 99% of the pc deployment process is automated. 

What I'm after is for the drives to be in the connected state the first time they are mapped.

Comment: Windows domain? Try Group Policy preferences? Not sure how many drives can be mapped with it but it's worth a try...